# What can cause a materialized view in Oracle 10g to stop fast refreshing?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, materialized-views

If I have materialized view in Oracle which is defined as `REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT` every 15 minutes.  It works when initially created and refreshes happily. What can cause it to stop fast refreshing?

I can see that it has stopped refreshing based on this:

```
select mview_name, last_refresh_date from all_mviews;
```

Comment: Please show us the complete CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW statement.

Comment: Yeah, why don't you show us your create statement and the create statements of the materialized view logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Things we've found seem to stop an MV from refreshing:
1. a change to the base table's DDL
2. if the MV is across a DB link, a problem with getting the data across the link (for example, we had a database here, and one remote.  If during a refresh, the connection between the two databases failed, then the refresh failed)

In the case of #1, the refresh fails and never ever works again and we have to recreate the MV.  In the case of #2, its been unclear if the refresh will ever pick up again.
Fast refresh MVs have proved to be unreliable for us so we've created a job in Windows scheduler to initiate our refreshes.

Answer (score 1):

A thing that occasionally happened during my last job was, that DBA activity sometimes set the parameter `job_queue_processes` to 0. This will stop materialized view refreshing until the parameter value is set to something greater than 0.

Comment: Thanks.  This is not the case here.  It refreshes correctly for a while and then something causes it to stop.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the materialized view. The following query from the oracle data dictionary will give you a list of all your (the oracle user's) materialized views and how fast refreshable they are.

```
SELECT MVIEW_NAME, FAST_REFRESHABLE FROM USER_MVIEWS;
```

The FAST_REFRESHABLE column will give you one of the following values:
**NO:** The materialized view is not fast refreshable, and hence is complex.

**DIRLOAD:** Fast refresh is supported only for direct loads.

**DML:** Fast refresh is supported only for DML operations.

**DIRLOAD_DML:** Fast refresh is supported for both direct loads and DML operations.

**DIRLOAD_LIMITEDDML:** Fast refresh is supported for direct loads and a subset of DML operations.

The ones that have given me problems in the past have been **DIRLOAD_LIMITEDDML**. I have usually gotten those if there is a COUNT, MAX, etc... in the MVIEW query. Usually these refresh on inserts and deletes but not on updates.

Comment: Thanks for that info.  The one in question is DIRLOAD_DML.

Comment: Does the one in question depend on any other MVIEWS?